# Disabled Rollout Button play console (No grey tick): Flutter update app App Bundle Format

Tags: android, flutter, updates, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

[image]

I have Checked all the Things like...
App content
App release
Store Listing
Content Rating
Pricing and Distribution

Not a single thing remain but still not getting button enabled..

(Previously i have successfully updated my app in APKS format)
wanted to update in app bundle format i don't thing this may be issue (modified and upgraded my app version etc).

Comment: Your app name is containing Beta or it is a beta version ??

Comment: and what you are trying is it to publish it to production release, may be

Comment: Also at the top, it has View Error Message click on and see what is the error message.

Comment: My App contains Beta Word, and yes i am already published it and now i am trying to update it.  and The Error message is like : Error
You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.

Comment: But it supports all the devices !!! i think may be be it is in bundle format previously it were multiple split APKS

Comment: If you publish bundle format the first time then you can only be able to upload bundle format for all future updates, not asks..., same for apks..

Comment: Android App Bundle Details : Native platforms 3 native platforms: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86_64  , Supported Android devices 10615 devices .... still getting error like : ""You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs""

Comment: Double check the versionCode\

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder  maybe that the issue... can you point me some Document or Source for the Same ?

Comment: Just reach out to play store team and they will give you the exact cause error.

Comment: Yes I already mailed support team and waiting for the response... just trying to figure out in mean time.. Thanks for your Reply @Rj_Innocent_Coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully Solved the issue...

What was the issue : The Error says You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs

How to solve : You also need to Upload APKS and maybe need to leave one of the Apk so you can ignore the another error like "one of the Apk is overriding the app bundle".

So in conclusion upload apk with app bundle and leave one of the Apk just select which one you want to leave...

Note :
Built using as split per abi.... 
And
Read error if you have any future error and try to solve it accordingly... :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with flutter and google play console. I had mistakenly given earlier version as 4003 and had hard time with errors in google play console. Solution was just one line in

> pubspec.yaml

The version is on the following line after the '+' sign and in my case it had to be bigger than 4003, so this one was fine:

```
version: 1.0.6+5000
```